# Tense problems : present tense or past tense?

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis, sequence-of-tenses

Tense problems. Can anyone help me with the following in the book *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Chapter 11: Qudditch, page 135:

> (1) ***That's*** where he was going when we saw him
>   (2) ***he's*** after whatever
>   ***it's*** guarding!
>   (3) "No - he wouldn't," she said. "I know ***he's*** not very
>   nice, but he wouldn't try and steal something Dumbledore was keeping
>   safe."

In the above context, can anyone tell me and explain to me:

> (1) "That's" actually means ***That is*** or ***That was***?
>   (2) "he's and it's
>   " actually mean ***he is*** and ***it is*** or ***he was*** and ***it was***?
>    (3)
>   "he's" actually means ***he is*** or ***he was***?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It means "**That is**." Since "it" is *still* there as they speak. It hasn't gone away; it hasn't turned into a thing of the past.